# Creating a radscheduler type grid asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to list a list of client with cell for each employee. radcheduler type. If u click on each cell u can assign a new value at this date for this employee. 
I though about place holder but someone says it is not efficient
any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with something that works nicely and decide to work on it as a software  for my own..Goood stuff !